# Why doesn't VS show my created database in the 'Select or Enter a Database name' dropdown list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I created a database named `sample` in SQL Server Mnagement Studio 2008 and I created a table too. But when I wanted to connect to the created database from the Visual Studio 2010, it did not show my created database.

All I did is I clicked:

```
Tools --> Connect to Database --> Selected the server name --> Clicked 'Use Windows Authentication'---> clicked the drop down list of 'Select or enter a database name'.
```

It didn't show my created database `sample` but showed `master, model, msdb, Reportserver, reportserverTempdb, Tempdb`.

If I enter the database name, I get the following error:

> This connection cannot be tested because the specified database does not exist or is not visible to the specified user

What could be the problem and how do I solve it? I am looking forward to solving this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you running visual studio as the same user as you used to create the the database in ssms?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you must have resolved this... otherwise I followed the following steps
Goto SQL Server Object explorer
Add the SQL server - your_pcname\SqlExpress
Add the new database
Create tables into it
Then - try to create the connection; it should show the new database created.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who came here just like me, in my sql server, there was a failed restore attempt of the same database. It said XYZDatabase (Restoring...). The issue got resolved when I deleted that failed restore.

Comment: For future reference, this sort of response would be better as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the correct server name of the specific database to which you want to connect.
Open SQL Server > Right click on the database which you want to connect > properties> Click View Connection Properties (In the left side written in blue color)> There is the server name, copy that and paste it in the Connection Server Name in Visual Studio Project on which you want the data.
I hope this helps.